# How do I limit the amount of numbers I have in a row?

Tags: c++, primes

I'm attempting to list a set of prime numbers from a lower bound to an upper bound limiting the number of prime numbers in a row to 8. Though I have done the first part, I can't get them to list in rows with only 8 prime numbers per row.

```
#include <iostream>
enter code here

int main()
{
    int low, high, i, flag, j;
    cout << "Enter two numbers(intervals): ";
    cin >> low >> high;
    cout << "Prime numbers between " << low << " and " << high << " are: ";
    while (low < high)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 2, j = 1; i <=low/2; +ii, ++j)
        {
            if (j == 8)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                j = j - 7;
            }
            else if (low % i == 0)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (flag == 0)
            cout << low << " ";
            ++low;
    }
return 0;
}
```

It works for the first row, then everything else seems to start listing rather than being in a row.

```
Output: Enter two numbers(intervals): 1
200
Prime numbers between 1 and 200 are: 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17
19
23
29
31 ...
```

Comment: May I ask what IDE you are using? There seem to be some unusual defaults.

Comment: Also you've got that while loop a bit convoluted, mind if I clean that up?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios, which I strongly dislike by ce la vie.

Comment: I don't mind at all.

Comment: Also, take a look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes, for future fiddling with primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little late, but I said I'd do it. My suggestions:

```
#include <iostream>
//enter code here
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    int low, high, count, i;
    bool flag; // bools are more suited to being flags
    cout << "Enter two numbers(intervals): ";
    cin >> low >> high;
    cout << "Prime numbers between " << low << " and " << high << " are: ";
    count = 1; // I replaced j with this for ease of reading
    while (low < high)
    {

        flag = true;
        // using break in loops is not recommended, and you already have a flag
        for (i = 2; i <= low / 2 && flag; ++i)
        {
            if (low % i == 0)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            cout << low;
            if (count == 8)
            {
                cout << std::endl;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
                ++count;
            }
        }
        ++low;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code divide not every 8 prime numbers, but every 8 attempts of dividing a number during search for prime number. So any prime that is 8 or more values away from previous will generate a line break. Consider following fix:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int low, high, i, flag, j;
    cout << "Enter two numbers(intervals): ";
    cin >> low >> high;
    cout << "Prime numbers between " << low << " and " << high << " are: ";
    j = 0;
    while (low < high)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <=low/2; ++i)
        {
            // Removed here
            if (low % i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            ++j; // Added here
            cout << low << " ";
        }
        if (j == 8) // and here
        {
            cout << "\n";
            j = j - 8;
        }
        ++low;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, you should end a search when reaching square root of `low`, not `low / 2`. The loop will be much faster.

Comment: I tried that before but I think I included the ++low in one of the if statements. Thank you so much

Comment: @AnthonyMastrangelo No problem :) Consider approving my answer (just 'tick' next to it)

Comment: @PiotrK please do not give people examples with `using namespace std;`, that's considered bad practice.

Comment: @Tzalumen Yes, I know. I was merely fixing the problem in code - and using namespace was not part of the problem - that's why I also did not coded sieve of Erastotheneses, which would be much better solution in that case.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is part of a general problem though. Shouldn't your given solutions at least correct such a common usage error?

Comment: @Tzalumen The OP did not asked for general solution. I don't want to pollute my answer with quasi-nazi-purity of language, where it does not matter in this concrete example. The better consideration on your part, would be why I didn't mention sieve of Erastotheneses, which is far more useful for OP at this stage. And yes, the OP will learn, sooner or later, that using namespace std; is evil in some concrete situations. But the using directive is a tool, and as all tools has some degree of usefulness. In this example its usefulness is to not pollute code with myriads of std::...